# State not persisting after restarting the app with hydrated bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

Before restarting
Got object store box in database hydrated_box.
AuthenticationState(AuthenticationStatus.unknown, User(-))
AuthenticationState(AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated, User(-))
AuthenticationState(AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, User(def25f08-37d9-49f6-97d8-5a2525a04d70))

After restarting
Restarted application in 124ms.
Got object store box in database hydrated_box.
{status: AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, user: {id: def25f08-37d9-49f6-97d8-5a2525a04d70}}
AuthenticationState(AuthenticationStatus.unknown, User(-))
AuthenticationState(AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated, User(-))

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
part of 'authentication_bloc.dart';

class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  const AuthenticationState._({
    this.status = AuthenticationStatus.unknown,
    this.user = User.empty,
  });

  const AuthenticationState.unknown() : this._();

  const AuthenticationState.authenticated(User user)
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, user: user);

  const AuthenticationState.unauthenticated()
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);

  final AuthenticationStatus status;
  final User user;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];

  @override
  bool get stringify => true;

  factory AuthenticationState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  return AuthenticationState._(
    status: AuthenticationStatus.values.firstWhere((status) => status.toString() == map['status']),
    user: User.fromMap(map),
  );
}
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
    'status': status.toString(),
    'user': user.toMap(),
  };
}

}
```

[Link for the repository](https://github.com/felangel/Bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_login)

```
Tried using hydrated bloc to persist state
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login/app.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: kIsWeb
        ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
        : await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
  
  runApp(const App());
}
```